# Importing an XML file into MS Access with transform file

Tags: xml, ms-access, import

I am trying to import an XML file into MS-Access, and I have searched extensively for an example of something similar to mine, but I have come up short. The result of importing without an XSLT file is that I only get the first row of values. For example, I get 2 tables: ABC and DEF, and both tables only have the first value in them ('1234567891011' and '12116360102', respectively). Ideally what I want is one table with 2 fields (ABC and DEF) with all the corresponding values. I can live with creating 2 separate tables, but that is not ideal since I have multiple XML files, and managing them will be easier in one table for each XML file. Here is a sample of the XML. Any help would be much appreciated. :

```
<Codes>
  <ABC>
    <Value>1234567891011</Value> 
    <Value>1234567891110</Value> 
    <Value>1234567891022</Value> 
  </ABC>
  <DEF>
    <Value>12116360102</Value> 
    <Value>65416360402</Value> 
    <Value>68559760202</Value> 
  </DEF>
</Codes>
```

Comment: Without XSLT file I expect will have to use VBA to open the file as text file object and read each line and write data to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the declarative, special-purpose, language (same type as SQL) designed to transform XML files from various structures to end-use formats including other XML, HTML, even txt/csv files.

Specifically, you need to migrate the root's children (*ABC*, *DEF*, etc.) into a new node like *Source* for each *Value* node in document. Change `<mytable>` in XSLT to name of table you want in MS Access and change `<Source>` to field name you want in that new table.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl file to be loaded in VBA)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Codes">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">          
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[name()='Value']">
    <mytable>
      <Source><xsl:value-of select="name(parent::*)"/></Source>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>   
    </mytable>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**VBA** *(note that the output file of transformation is imported in Access)*

```vb
Public Sub TransformAndImportXML()
    ' INCLUDE Microsoft XML, v3.0 REFERENCE
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XML\Input.xml"
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XML\File.xsl"

    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\XML\Output.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing

    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\XML\Output.xml"
    MsgBox "Successfully transformed and imported XML!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

**XML** Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Codes>
  <mytable>
    <Source>ABC</Source>
    <Value>1234567891011</Value>
  </mytable>
  <mytable>
    <Source>ABC</Source>
    <Value>1234567891110</Value>
  </mytable>
  <mytable>
    <Source>ABC</Source>
    <Value>1234567891022</Value>
  </mytable>
  <mytable>
    <Source>DEF</Source>
    <Value>12116360102</Value>
  </mytable>
  <mytable>
    <Source>DEF</Source>
    <Value>65416360402</Value>
  </mytable>
  <mytable>
    <Source>DEF</Source>
    <Value>68559760202</Value>
  </mytable>
</Codes>
```

**MS Access** Import *(mytable contents)*

```
Source          Value
   ABC  1234567891011
   ABC  1234567891110
   ABC  1234567891022
   DEF    12116360102
   DEF    65416360402
   DEF    68559760202
```

Comment: Thankyou! That worked! My goal was to create a simple solution for some non-technical people on our team, and I was worried about a solution that involved having them run VBA, but simply using the XSLT to transform the import will work well for them.

Comment: Great to hear. Glad I could help. Please accept solution (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution!

Comment: Thank you Parfait! How would you apply this approach to a more complex task of iterating through enclosed folder structure, which contains multiple XML files like this one ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019902/importing-multiple-xml-files-from-folder-structure-into-ms-access )?